# Google Adwords script runs on AWS Lambda:[Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/home/sbx_user1051'

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, google-ads-api

A python script fetch google adwords report, it working as expected in my local machine, but when deployed in AWS Lambda function, I got the following error

```
{
  "errorMessage": "[Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/home/sbx_user1051'",
  "errorType": "OSError",
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/var/task/lambda_function.py",
      24,
      "lambda_handler",
      "report_downloader = client.GetReportDownloader(version='v201809')"
    ],
    [
      "/var/task/googleads/adwords.py",
      370,
      "GetReportDownloader",
      "return ReportDownloader(self, version, server)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/task/googleads/adwords.py",
      1213,
      "__init__",
      "self.proxy_config, self._namespace, self._adwords_client.cache)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/task/googleads/common.py",
      819,
      "__init__",
      "transport = _ZeepProxyTransport(timeout, proxy_config, cache)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/task/googleads/common.py",
      667,
      "__init__",
      "cache = zeep.cache.SqliteCache()"
    ],
    [
      "/var/task/zeep/cache.py",
      77,
      "__init__",
      "self._db_path = path if path else _get_default_cache_path()"
    ],
    [
      "/var/task/zeep/cache.py",
      155,
      "_get_default_cache_path",
      "os.makedirs(path)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/os.py",
      210,
      "makedirs",
      "makedirs(head, mode, exist_ok)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/os.py",
      210,
      "makedirs",
      "makedirs(head, mode, exist_ok)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/os.py",
      220,
      "makedirs",
      "mkdir(name, mode)"
    ]
  ]
}
```

I know in Lambda it could only write files located in tem folder, but what confused me is that in my script, I don't write to any file at all, here is the main structure of my script:

```
client = adwords.AdWordsClient.LoadFromStorage('tmp/googleads.yaml')
report_downloader = client.GetReportDownloader(version='v201809')
report_query = (adwords.ReportQueryBuilder()
                  .Select( str)
                  .From('ACCOUNT_PERFORMANCE_REPORT')
                  .During('LAST_7_DAYS')
                  .Build())
results=report_downloader.DownloadReportAsStringWithAwql( report_query, 'TSV', skip_report_header=True, skip_column_header=True, skip_report_summary=True, include_zero_impressions=False)
campaigns=results.splitlines()
```

Please advise how to fix this issue. The env is python 3.6

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like Adwords is using a cache and, by default, that cache goes into the home directory of the user running your code.  To fix this, set the environment variable `XDG_CACHE_HOME` to `/tmp/.cache`.  You can set this in the Lambda environment variables.

Comment: Hi, This env setting does fix the issue. Just curious how do you know I should add the setting for this variable? From error message?

Comment: @YangL - I followed the source code.  The last error in `common.py` points [here](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib/blob/master/googleads/common.py#L667).  That line of code ultimately points [here](https://github.com/mvantellingen/python-zeep/blob/master/src/zeep/cache.py#L158) and that one led me to [here](https://github.com/ActiveState/appdirs/blob/master/appdirs.py#L265).  Your errors show Unix paths so that led me to [this line](https://github.com/ActiveState/appdirs/blob/master/appdirs.py#L314).  That is what open source is all about sometimes.

Comment: Nearly 5 years later, this fix is still working, for those that are running into this issue trying to deploy on Lambda- I wish it was showing up more often in the searches. The XDG_CACHE_HOME variable is an incredibly useful tip (especially for those running into issues with Zeep and the new googleads python lib)